# How do I adjust the settings of Gmail to enable the "Quick-mark as important" feature?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

My personal Gmail account has an option (next to the star — which stars emails), to quickly mark an email as important. However, my second Gmail account does not have this facility, and I really need this feature.

I have compared the settings between the two of them and can't work out what I am missing on the new account.

Can anyone help? Here are two examples of with and without the desired feature.

[image]

[image]